# Library not loaded: libboost_python.dylib

Tags: python

when I import modules, error occurs :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/zhangshirui/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-mac64/naoqi.py", line 7, in <module>
    import qi
  File "/Users/zhangshirui/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-mac64/qi/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from _qi import Application as _Application
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/zhangshirui/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-mac64/_qi.so, 2): Library not loaded: libboost_python.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/zhangshirui/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-mac64/_qi.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libboost_python.dylib in /Users/zhangshirui/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-mac64/_qi.so with restricted binary
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing happened to me when I updated my OSX. I always have system integrity protection disabled on my laptop and when I updated OSX, my preference got overridden and it got enabled again.

Looking at the permissions issue it seemed related to it. So I ran 
 `csrutil disable`  
in recovery mode.

Please refer to this to find out about disabling system integrity protection.

http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html

That made it work.

Thanks,

Dinesh